# How can I set LANG to ascii?

Tags: linux, bash, utf-8

I'm accessing an Ubuntu machine using PuTTY, and using gcc.

The default `LANG` environment variable on this machine is set to `en_NZ.UTF-8`, which causes GCC to think PuTTY is capable of displaying UTF-8 text, which it doesn't seem to be. 
Maybe it's my font, I don't know - it does this:

```
foo.c:1: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â at end of input
```

If I set it with `export LANG=en_NZ`, then this causes GCC to behave correctly, I get:

```
foo.c:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' at end of input
```

but this then causes everything else to go wrong. For example

```
man foo
man: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
```

I've trawled Google and I can't for the life of me find out what I have to put in there for it to just use ASCII. `en_NZ.ASCII` doesn't work, nor do any of the other things I can find.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LANG=en_NZ` is correct. However, you must make locale files for `en_NZ`.

For Ubuntu, edit `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` and add `en_NZ ISO-8859-1` to the file. If your system is another distribution (including Debian), the location will be different. Look at `/usr/sbin/locale-gen` and see where it stores this info.

Afterwards, run `locale-gen` to create the `en_NZ` locale file. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Putty can display utf - I think it is in appearance -> translation (or something, I don't have access to it right now).

Answer (score 0):

For Debian 5.0 Lenny:

```
aptitude install locales
```

If that's already installed:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```